# Creating a custom Property Pane Field

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm trying to create a custom property pane field to allow the user to configure a list and then a list view to be used by the web part.

I followed the instructions of this [Custom field example](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Integrating-Property-Pane) section.

First, the interface of the example code seems to be different from my environment. In my environment, `onRender` only takes the `HTMLElement` to render the custom control in. There's no `context` nor `onChanged` parameters.

Secondly, if I ignore those differences, I can get my control to render on the page but I can't figure out how to tell SharePoint to save the selected value to a property. I was looking at how the [TextField works](http://pastebin.com/SsKiT23u) and there's a get value property that I tried implementing in my control but didn't have any luck.

Does anyone have a working example of a custom property pane field?

Comment: Adding the code you have so far will help users to answer your question.

Comment: It seems the tutorial is out of date. You might want to open an issue here: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues

Comment: Here's the current version of the control: http://pastebin.com/J7am7RqE

Note that currently I don't have the dropdown for the views, I'm trying to make it work first with just a selection of a list to reduce complexity.

To use the component, first you of course have to import it to your web part. The following code show's how I'm rendering it to the property pane: http://pastebin.com/r89uWHKi

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've updated the documentation (https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Integrating-Property-Pane) so that it now works.

For now, it's the responsibility of the developer to know what properties are being affected by the control (it could be one or many), and write them back to the host webpart.

I'll add one more thing.  If you are doing this to populate a dropdown with SharePoint data, take a look at this post - [SharePoint Framework web parts - dynamic properties pane](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191169/sharepoint-framework-web-parts-dynamic-properties-pane)

Comment: Thank you @PatMill_MSFT. Writing the property back to the host worked for me.

Comment: Is https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/integrate-with-property-pane where the answer's https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Integrating-Property-Pane has moved to? Is it the "same" document?