# How to call an API request in the .ts file spfx not the main component

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, spfx-custom-property-pane

This is my web part below, I need to call an API so I can dynamically populate the scope property dropdown that are provided as 'settings' to the web part.

Can I use componentdidmount? Doesn't seem to be working when I try that though.

The API im trying to call is the getEvents()

```
import { WebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { AadHttpClient, HttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

export interface IUpcomingEventsWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  layoutToggle: boolean;
  headerToggle: boolean;
  tooltipToggle: boolean;
  scope: string;
  dateRange: string;
  category: string;
  context: WebPartContext;
}

export default class UpcomingEventsWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IUpcomingEventsWebPartProps> {
  
  private httpClient: AadHttpClient;
  public getEvents() {
    this.httpClient.post('https://********.azurewebsites.net/api/GetEvents', AadHttpClient.configurations.v1, {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "RangeStartDate": '2021-01-01',
        "RangeEndDate": '2050-01-01',
      })
    })
    .then((res: HttpClientResponse): Promise<any> => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(res => {
     console.log(res);
    })
  }

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IUpcomingEventsProps> = React.createElement(
      UpcomingEvents,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        scope: this.properties.scope,
        context: this.context
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: 'Title'
                }),
                PropertyPaneDropdown('scope', {
                  label:'Scope',
                  options: [
                    { key: 'All', text: 'All' },
                    { key: 'United Kingdom', text: 'United Kingdom' },
                    { key: 'Germany', text: 'Germany' },
                    { key: 'Mexico', text: 'Mexico' },
                    { key: 'SPAIN', text: 'SPAIN' }
                  ],
                  selectedKey: 'All',
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: You definitely should be able to make API calls and initiate them from `componentDidMount`.  Where is that in your code though? I don't see `componentDidMount` in there or anywhere else where you call `getEvents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to load the data in your `OnInit()` method, and then reference it in your property pane.

Similar thread: [SharePoint Framework web parts - dynamic properties pane](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191169/sharepoint-framework-web-parts-dynamic-properties-pane)

Additional Reference:

1. [SharePoint Framework: how to properly dynamically populate dropdown property pane fields](https://www.wictorwilen.se/blog/sharepoint-framework-how-to-properly-dynamically-populate-dropdown-property-pane-fields/)